# Unable to update or uninstall sfdx cli

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm unable to update my sfdx cli.

Installed via the installer here: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli

I've tried uninstalling via the instructions provided, but sfdx remains installed. I've tried reinstalling via the installer, but the sfdx version remains the same.

Is there any way to get my sfdx cli up to date?

MacOS version 10.14.6
sfdx cli version 7.92.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same happened to me a few days ago (stuck in CLI 7.94.3 without updates via sfdx update)

My fix:
Check your installation method(s) (via npm/yarn or via the [installer](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)).

The 'which' command will point to the bin directory containing sfdx

```
$ which sfdx
```

If yarm/npm: remove the CLI:

```
$ yarn global remove sfdx-cli
```

or

```
$ npm uninstall -g sfdx-cli
```

If installed via the installation program: as already done follow the [CLI Setup Guide instructions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/sfdx ~/.config/sfdx ~/.cache/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/sfdx
```

This will keep the login information contained in your ~/.sfdx directory

Then reinstall from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli
and if required

```
$ sfdx update
```

or

```
$ sfdx update stable-rc
```

to use the Release Candidate version.

Hope this can help

```
$ sfdx version --json
```

{
"cliVersion": "sfdx-cli/7.108.0",
"architecture": "darwin-x64",
"nodeVersion": "node-v14.17.1"
}

Comment: This worked for me when I did a restart after uninstalling

Comment: Dave Carroll has put this in a gist to uninstall from Mac OSX before you reinstall with npm
https://gist.github.com/dcarroll/318e5f2d44fb6c2e612dd8d817473cdb

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried `Sfdx update` ?
Additionally, when you uninstall a CLI make sure you close your existent terminal and open a new one.